# Regression Test Fails on Postgres v12

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to install AGE on my system running macOS 12.6.3 with PostgreSQL REL_12_STABLE. I am using the AGE_PG12.1.0_ALPHA branch for the installation. After running the install command, I've done the regression tests using installcheck, which tells me that 2 tests have failed and that that there is an error. I understand that the error is not a big deal as it is just due to the return value of string comparisons on macOS being different, but am not sure about the failed tests. Are they significant and is there a way to fix them?

Here are the series of Terminal lines:

```
➜  age git:(AGE_PG12.1.0_ALPHA) make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-12/bin/pg_config installcheck
/usr/local/pgsql-12/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/usr/local/pgsql-12/bin'    --load-extension=age --inputdir=.//regress --outputdir=.//regress --temp-instance=.//regress/instance --port=61958 --encoding=UTF-8 --dbname=contrib_regression scan graphid agtype catalog cypher expr cypher_create cypher_match cypher_unwind cypher_set cypher_remove cypher_delete cypher_with cypher_vle cypher_union cypher_merge age_load index drop
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============
============== starting postmaster                    ==============
running on port 61958 with PID 69718
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== installing age                         ==============
CREATE EXTENSION
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test scan                         ... ok          636 ms
test graphid                      ... ok           37 ms
test agtype                       ... FAILED      140 ms
test catalog                      ... FAILED      179 ms
test cypher                       ... ok           55 ms
test expr                         ... ok          890 ms
test cypher_create                ... ok          223 ms
test cypher_match                 ... ok          535 ms
test cypher_unwind                ... ok           63 ms
test cypher_set                   ... ok          171 ms
test cypher_remove                ... ok          187 ms
test cypher_delete                ... ok          174 ms
test cypher_with                  ... ok           59 ms
test cypher_vle                   ... ok         1574 ms
test cypher_union                 ... ok           80 ms
test cypher_merge                 ... ok          191 ms
test age_load                     ... ok         2858 ms
test index                        ... ok          151 ms
test drop                         ... ok          357 ms
============== shutting down postmaster               ==============

=======================
 2 of 19 tests failed. 
=======================

The differences that caused some tests to fail can be viewed in the
file "/Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/regression.diffs".  A copy of the test summary that you see
above is saved in the file "/Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/regression.out".

make: *** [installcheck] Error 1
```

```
➜  age git:(AGE_PG12.1.0_ALPHA) cat regress/regression.diffs
diff -U3 /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/expected/agtype.out /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/results/agtype.out
--- /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/expected/agtype.out    2023-02-23 12:12:51.000000000 -0800
+++ /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/results/agtype.out 2023-02-23 12:13:28.000000000 -0800
@@ -2886,7 +2886,7 @@
 SELECT agtype_btree_cmp('"string"'::agtype, '"string "'::agtype);
  agtype_btree_cmp 
 ------------------
-               -1
+              -32
 (1 row)

 SELECT agtype_btree_cmp(NULL, NULL);
diff -U3 /Users/kenwoon/age/./regress/expected/catalog.out /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/results/catalog.out
--- /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/expected/catalog.out   2023-02-23 12:12:51.000000000 -0800
+++ /Users/kenwoon/Desktop/age/./regress/results/catalog.out    2023-02-23 12:13:28.000000000 -0800
@@ -61,10 +61,10 @@
 drop cascades to table g._ag_label_vertex
 drop cascades to table g._ag_label_edge
 drop cascades to table g.v
-ERROR:  table "v" is for label "v"
+ERROR:  table "v" is for label ""
 -- DROP TABLE ... should fail
 DROP TABLE g.v;
-ERROR:  table "v" is for label "v"
+ERROR:  table "v" is for label ""
 -- should fail (cascade = false)
 SELECT drop_graph('g');
 ERROR:  cannot drop schema g because other objects depend on it
```

Comment: You can try building for branch PG12 instead of AGE_PG12.1.0_ALPHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not very significant. You can ignore them for now as the [official tutorial](https://youtu.be/0-qMwpDh0CA?t=232) ignored when running the regression test in mac.

Hopefully in new release this will be fixed.